# Most efficient way to loop through data with PHP

Tags: php, loops

I am currently refactoring a website and I've come across a group of links which all look the same but have a few different variable/text.

I understand loops and everything and that's definitely what is needed but I'm just not sure how best to deal with the various pieces of data which change.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="featuredSide" style="border-color:#fff">
    <h3 style="font-size: 20px; margin-bottom: 12px;">$sectionName</h3>
    <img src="images/$imageName.jpg" width="50" height="60" style="float: left; margin: 4px 8px 16px 0px; border: 2px solid #fff;" />
    <h4 style="font-size: 11px;">$author</h4>
    <p class="lineAboveCol" style="clear: both; margin-bottom: 0px;"><a href="resources.php?section=$section">Click here for more information</a></p>
</div>
```

I've put in variables to replace the data that will change (these are all currently done in HTML).

So what would be the best way to loop through this data, I thought of using simple arrays but I don't think that's particularly easy to maintain in the long run. Is there a simple solution I'm missing or would it even be worth setting this data up in a MySQL table and pulling it directly from there?

Thanks.

Comment: Just create an array of `array('sectionName' => 'author', 'anotherSectionName' => 'anotherAuthor');` and do `foreach ($array as $sectionName => $author)` **EDIT** Oh wait I just noticed those other variables in there as well - but the concept is sound, only create an array of arrays and access the individual keys of the sub arrays.

Comment: Could we have some more info. Such as the number of pages containing this. The number of occurances of this div etc

Comment: This is an include file, this piece of code is repeated 8 times in that file. The file is included in a handful of pages, maybe 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start with an array:

```
$links = array(
    'section1' => array(
        'section'    => '...',
        'sectioName' => '...',
        'imageName'  => '...',
        'author'     => '...',
    //    'text' => 'Click here for more information',
    ),
);
```

and then I'd run a loop. It is easily adaptable, you keep distinct presentation and data, and you can move it to MySQL or other persistence layer in the future, maybe supply a backend interface to allow maintainers to edit sections.

Should some variations between sections be needed, you can pull them into keys of the arrays (or columns in MySQL).

You can also supply the HTML from outside and run a preg_replace of special tags, e.g. `{{ author }}` is replaced by the content of `$currentSection['author']` and so on. This is easily portable to any template engine, too.

Comment: Great, I think this is the most elegant solution, easy to maintain and read too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could do this..

```
<?php
$theVars[0]['sectionName'] = "section name 1";
$theVars[0]['section'] = "section 1";
$theVars[0]['author'] = "author 1";
$theVars[1]['sectionName'] = "section name 2";
$theVars[1]['section'] = "section 2";
$theVars[1]['author'] = "author 2";
$theVars[2]['sectionName'] = "section name 3";
$theVars[2]['section'] = "section 3";
$theVars[2]['author'] = "author 3";

$htmlStr = "";    

for($i=0;$i<=2;$i++){
    $htmlStr .= '<div class="featuredSide" style="border-color:#fff">
                 <h3 style="font-size: 20px; margin-bottom: 12px;">'.$theVars[$i]['sectionName'].'</h3>
                 <img src="images/$imageName.jpg" width="50" height="60" style="float: left; margin: 4px 8px 16px 0px; border: 2px solid #fff;" />
                 <h4 style="font-size: 11px;">'.$theVars[$i]['author'].'</h4>
                 <p class="lineAboveCol" style="clear: both; margin-bottom: 0px;"><a href="resources.php?section='.$theVars[$i]['section'].'">Click here for more information</a></p>
                 </div>';
}

echo $htmlStr;

?>
```

Am I in the ballpark?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use php array for this particular thing but have the array in a different file so it's easy to update/upload

The code I'd use would be something like

**section.values.php**

```
$sections = array(
    'Section 1' => 'Author 1',
    'Section 2' => 'Author 2',
);
```

**Then on the html/php page:**

```
<?php
    include("section.values.php"); //or any file name

    foreach($sections as $sectionName => $author){
        echo '<div class="featuredSide" style="border-color:#fff">
            <h3 style="font-size: 20px; margin-bottom: 12px;">' . $sectionName . '</h3>
            <img src="images/$imageName.jpg" width="50" height="60" style="float: left; margin: 4px 8px 16px 0px; border: 2px solid #fff;" />
            <h4 style="font-size: 11px;">' . $author . '</h4>
            <p class="lineAboveCol" style="clear: both; margin-bottom: 0px;"><a href="resources.php?section=' . $section . '">Click here for more information</a></p>
            </div>';
    }
?>
```